# Kafka Streams parallel processing not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm learning Kafka Stream and I want to build a simple application that reads lines of text from one topic and puts number of letter occurrences to InfluxDB. My second goal is to run it in parallel. I would like to have two running instances of Kafka Stream both of them processing input at the same time but from different partitions. Unfortunately, after I launch both instances only one of them is working second one is waiting.

My configuration is as follows:
* input topic has 4 partitions
* Stream application has a property `num.stream.threads` set to 2

Here is the source code:

```java
public class LineStatisticsStream {

  static Pattern letterPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]");
  InfluxDB influxDB;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new LineStatisticsStream().start();
  }

  Properties getStreamProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"lineStatistics4");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG,2);
    return properties;
  }

  Topology getStreamTopology(ForeachAction<String,Long> action) {
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KStream<String,String> linesStream = builder.stream("lines", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()));
    linesStream.flatMapValues(this::findAllLetters)
        .map((k,v)-> KeyValue.pair(v,v))
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.String()))
        .count()
        .toStream()
        .to("letterCount",Produced.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long()));

    KStream<String,Long> countStream = builder.stream("letterCount", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long()));
    countStream.peek(action);
    return builder.build();
  }

  private void insertToInfluxDB(String letter, Long count) {
    influxDB.write(Point.measurement("lettersCount")
        .tag("letter",letter)
        .time(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .addField("count", count)
        .build()
       );
  }

  private List<String> findAllLetters(String s) {
    List<String> letters = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher=    letterPattern.matcher(s.toLowerCase());
    while(matcher.find()) {
      letters.add(matcher.group(0));
    }
    return letters;
  }

  private void start() {
    influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8086");
    influxDB.setDatabase("letters");
    influxDB.enableBatch(BatchOptions.DEFAULTS);

    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(getStreamTopology(this::insertToInfluxDB), getStreamProperties());
    streams.start();
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(()->{streams.close();influxDB.close();}));

  }
}
```

And last few lines of a log from "waiting" application:

```
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:982 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Found no committed offset for partition lines4-2
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:982 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Found no committed offset for partition lines4-1
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  RocksDBTimestampedStore:82 - Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003 in regular mode
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  RocksDBTimestampedStore:82 - Opening store KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003 in regular mode
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1068 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-2-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1068 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-2-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  StreamThread:212 - stream-thread [lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-2] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1068 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  KafkaConsumer:1068 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1-restore-consumer, groupId=null] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  StreamThread:212 - stream-thread [lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to RUNNING
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  KafkaStreams:263 - stream-client [lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099] State transition from REBALANCING to RUNNING
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:982 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Found no committed offset for partition lines4-1
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:982 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Found no committed offset for partition lines4-2
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:525 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Setting offset for partition lineStatistics4-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=73, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}}
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:525 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Setting offset for partition lines4-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=63, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}}
2019-11-18 21:27:16 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:525 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Setting offset for partition lineStatistics4-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000003-repartition-3 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=40, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=localhost:9092 (id: 1 rack: null), epoch=0}}
2019-11-18 21:27:17 INFO  SubscriptionState:348 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-2-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Resetting offset for partition lines4-1 to offset 0.
2019-11-18 21:27:17 INFO  SubscriptionState:348 - [Consumer clientId=lineStatistics4-5e5e2a71-2a3b-4e51-9d4c-4e470a8a8099-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=lineStatistics4] Resetting offset for partition lines4-2 to offset 0.
```

Comment: It's only info logs. Seems partitions `1` and `2` from topic `lines4` are assigned, so it should process data (if there is any). The other instance has partitions `0` and `3` assigned?

Comment: 1. Ensure data is produced evenly to partitions in the topic. 
2. Use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` utility to show how your consumers are acting on the partitions on the group. Please print output here and we can give you more info back :)